# how i can solve this problem on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web, plugins, wordpress-shortcode

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/bonusfunnel.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/master-popups-lite/includes/class-functions.php(549): implode()
#1 /home/bonusfunnel.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/master-popups-lite/includes/class-popups.php(272): MasterPopups\Includes\Functions::url_google_fonts()
#2 /home/bonusfunnel.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/master-popups-lite/includes/class-popups.php(247): MasterPopups\Includes\Popups->get_link_google_fonts()
#3 /home/bonusfunnel.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(303): MasterPopups\Includes\Popups->add_popups_to_admin_footer()
#4 /home/bonusfunnel.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#5 /home/bonusfunnel.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action()
#6 /home/bonusfunnel.com/public_html/wp-admin/admin-footer.php(78): do_action()
#7 /home/bonusfunnel.com/public_html/wp-admin/post.php(369): require_once('...')
#8 {main}
  thrown
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9FNj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B62KX.png)

Comment: Please avoid screenshots of error messages; it is much easier for others to find your question that way. Screenshots can be [supplementary useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303816), but mostly for visualizations.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This appears to be about administering WordPress, not about programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

generate_do_element_classes() is a new function in GP 2.2.

If your child theme is using it, you need to make sure your parent theme is running at least 2.2.

In that case, the function should be defined: https://github.com/tomusborne/generatepress/blob/2.2.1/inc/markup.php#L20

Perhaps your server has caching which is still serving the old files?

Let me know if that helps or not?

Comment: Where Can i Check if the theme is running on 2.2